# How to dynamically add data to a dataframe?

Tags: r, sqlite, dataframe, rsqlite

I have data I need to clean for each row in a file, and I want to insert the cleaned data in a SQLite3 database.  I'm using the [RSQLite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html) library which requires a [dataframe](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html).  Here's the code I trying to get working:

```
# Select feature names for use as column names in X train/test loading
feature_names <- unlist(dbGetQuery(con, "select feature_name from features order by feature_id"), use.names = FALSE);

# Load X training data
X_train_lines <- readLines("data/train/X_train.txt"); # Space delimited with leading and trailing spaces
X_train_values <- vector("list", length(X_train_lines));
names(X_train_values) <- feature_names; # colnames or names?
for (index in 1:length(X_train_lines)) {
  cleaned_line <- gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", X_train_lines[index], perl=TRUE); # remove extraneous whitespaces
  X_train_values[index] <- strsplit(cleaned_line, " "); # Wondering if X_train_values[index] is correct? 
}
# Write features data to features table
dbWriteTable(con, "X_train", as.data.frame(X_train_values), row.names = FALSE);
```

While the code executes without incident, when I attempt to look at the database using DbVisualizer I get an error:

```
An error occurred while performing the operation:
malformed database schema (X_train) - too many columns on X_train
```

My only guess is that rows and columns are somehow transposed.  My column names should be the value of the `feature_names` vector.

Also, if anyone has any suggestions for a better approach...

**UPDATE**

I tried doing a dput, though I had no idea what I was looking at. Here's the top of the summary:

```
head(summary(X_train_values))

                   Length Class    Mode       
tBodyAcc-mean()-X "561"  "-none-" "character"
tBodyAcc-mean()-Y "561"  "-none-" "character"
tBodyAcc-mean()-Z "561"  "-none-" "character"
tBodyAcc-std()-X  "561"  "-none-" "character"
tBodyAcc-std()-Y  "561"  "-none-" "character"
tBodyAcc-std()-Z  "561"  "-none-" "character"
```

Again, this leads me to believe the data is all mixed up.  It should have 561 columns, some of which are represented above as tBodyAcc-mean()-X etc.  The column values should be floating-point numbers which I don't see above.

The table command did not work:

```
table(X_train_values)
Error in table(X_train_values) : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

I should have 7,352 rows with 561 columns.

**UPDATE 2**

I believe my problem is that I'm trying to use a list like an array or arrays.  In Ruby, for example, I could do something like this:

```
x_train_values = []
x_train_lines.each { |line| x_train_values << line.split(' ') }
```

Comment: even a partial `dput(X_train_Values)` would be rly handy

Comment: You don't need a for loop to do a gsub on a vector, simply `gsub("old","new",vector)` will work

Comment: If you make a list and then call a function that coerces to a dataframe, then each list element becomes a column, so it just like the 'transposition' that happens with `apply(dat, 1, ...)`. If you constructed an example using one of the built-in databases in the packages you are using then people might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

In the following lines

```
for (index in 1:length(X_train_lines)) {
    cleaned_line <- gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", X_train_lines[index], perl=TRUE);
    X_train_values[index] <- strsplit(cleaned_line, " ");
}
```

you are using single square brackets (`[`) to access the columns of a data frame, when you should be using double ones (`[[`). When you use `X_train_lines[index]`, a *data frame* is returned, which has one column, equal to `X_train_lines[index]`. When you use `X_train_lines[[index]]`, however, the actual contents of that column are returned (see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html for more details).

Now, the way `gsub` works, is that it first converts its argument to a character using `as.character` and then processes it. In your case, `X_train_lines[index]` returns a data.frame whose single column is a factor (I guess) and therefore when coerced to a character you will get the factor levels, not the actual contents! So you are actually calling `gsub` on a string that looks like "1:2:3:...". If you use double brackets instead, then `gsub` will coerce a factor (instead of a data frame) to a character, which will work as desired.

As an aside, in R you do not need to end your lines with `;`. This is needed only to separate multiple statements on the same line.

Finally, it is best to try and avoid `for` loops because they can be slow and because there are more efficient functions with simpler syntax that can usually accomplish what you need (like `lapply`, `apply`, `sweep`, etc). For column/row/element-wise operations on a data frame/matrix/etc you can use `apply`, in which case your code will look like

```
apply(X_train_values, 2, gsub, pattern = "^ *|(?<= ) | *$",
    replacement = "", perl = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications/tips! The reason I'm using a loop is because my X_train data file is space delimited, but also could have extra leading spaces for each column to accommodate a minus sign. Once I've stripped the extra spaces I split the row by spaces to get the correct column values. Then I'm trying to force it to a data.frame so I can save it in the database. Not ideal, but I couldn't think of another way since I'm an R novice.

Comment: OK I see... I think your `for` loop should work anyway, just replace `[` with `[[` in `X_train_lines[index]`. I was just suggesting `apply` as a more "R-friendly" way of doing it. But you can keep the `for` loop if it works for you.